# Displaying fields in php from MS Access database

Tags: php, database, ms-access, connectivity

I have a simple `studentinfo.accdb`. I was able to connect to this database using php. Moreover, the values of the 'ID' column(primary key) are also being displayed. however, the field values are not. The error message is:

```
Connected
ID : 1
Warning: odbc_result(): Field class not found in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\connect\index.php on line 20
```

The following is my code:-

```
<?php

$con=odbc_connect("studentinfo", "", "");
if($con)
{
    echo "Connected<br>";
}
else
{
 echo "Failed";
} 

$sql="select * from Table1 WHERE ID = 1";
$result=odbc_exec($con, $sql);
while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "ID : ". $row['ID'];
if(isset($_GET['tName'])){
 echo "NAME : ". $row['tName'];}

$asd = odbc_result($result, "class");
echo $asd;
// echo "CLASS :".$row['class'];
echo "<br/>"; 
}
?>
```

I have used an isset() and clearly the fileds are not set for some reason. Please help!

Comment: why not use `$row['class']` like for your other fields? Does that work?

Comment: Tried that first, it doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" how? An error? Or simply nothing displayed? Is "class" definitely the name of your field? It's not "Class" for instance?

Comment: The error is the same. "Field not found". i have checked the field names over and over again, they are exactly how they are written. Don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: One use thing might be to use `print_r($row);` to check what all the columns available in the row are.

Comment: The simplest trick got the job done. I feel like a noob now. I was accessing a different database altogether! Thank you for being patient in helping this noob.

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it. I've voted to close the question, or you can just delete it since it's of no real value to anyone.